# Fill an array with 4 unique random numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, random

For a school project I need to do MasterMind, and all the 4 numbers of the secret code have to be different.

How can I create an array with 4 unique random numbers?

Here is my code so far:

```
srand(time(NULL));

for (j = 0; j <= 4; j++) { rand(); } 

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { vetor[i] = (1 + rand() % 8); }
```

Comment: What are the available colours (range of the numbers)? Maybe, you could provide the definition of an `enum` of your colours? Also, Mastermind does not require the individual colours of the code to be different. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't need colours, just 4 numbers from 1 to 8, the problem is that I can't have two equal numbers like 1 1 2 3, they need to be different. This is the code I have rigth now: 

 `srand(time(NULL));
 for (j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
   rand();
  }
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   vetor[i] = (1 + rand() % 8);
  }`

Comment: I see, what's your j-loop running for? Anyways, I'll add an answer. I'll take this as a reference: `vetor[i] = (1 + rand() % 8)` from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems in your code:**

1. The j-loop is running in vain
2. You are not checking for duplicates

**Solution:**

Here is a working code with explanation in the code comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    // Going to be filled with 4 unique random numbers
    int arr[4];

    // Set the seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Get 4 random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // Fill arr[i] with a random number from your specified range
        arr[i] = 1 + rand() % 8;

        // Try again if it is a duplicate
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                --i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the array and see the results
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use rand() function it give random value
Ex-
A[i] =rand()